# Can I use Async.js library in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have to call an api : `/1/dir/{imgID}` many times(average 50 times) using variation in `imgID`.

In node.js i can use [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) library. Can I use this library in Angular side? If yes then give me some idea how is it possible and if no then give me some alternative idea so that i can use this in AngularJS?

Comment: AngularJS implements $q service, try to read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Yes you can, but promises are the better alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Basically, you need to use `$q.all(promises);`, which can combine multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when all of the input promises are resolved.

Example:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2772-exploring-asynchronous-promise-based-workflows-in-angularjs.htm

Document:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Demo:
http://bennadel.github.io/JavaScript-Demos/demos/error-workflow-promises-angularjs/